# Calculating $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\int_0^\infty du_i\right)\min\left[e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n u_i},e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i}\right]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Let $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R_+}$, $i=1,...,n$ with $\lambda_i \neq 1$.

I know that the 'step' function for $u\in\mathbb{R}$ ( $\theta(u)=1$ for $u>0$ and $\theta(u)=0$ for $u<1$) has the integral representation

$$\theta(u)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{e^{zu}}{z+\epsilon}\,dz\tag{1}$$

for an infinitesimal $\epsilon$.

With the help of $(1)$ and the residue theorem (that I am hardly familiar with) I have to calculate

$$Q(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\int_0^\infty du_i\right)\min\left[e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n u_i},e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i}\right]\tag{2}$$

While doing this I am asked to prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i -1)^{n-1}\prod_{i\neq j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_i -\lambda_j}=1.$$

To be honest I dont know how to even start on this.
Any help or tip is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\residue}{\operatorname*{Res}}$
We need the following consequence of the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). Denote
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{C}_{+}&:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re z>0\},
\\ \mathbb{C}_{-}&:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re z<0\},
\\ C_R&:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=R\},
\\ i\mathbb{R}&:=\{iz:z\in\mathbb{R}\},
\\ \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}f(z)\,dz&:=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-iR}^{iR}f(z)\,dz.
\end{align}

> Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$ where $S$ is a finite set.
>
> 1. If $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=0$, then $\sum\limits_{s\in S}\residue\limits_{z=s}f(z)=0$.
> 2. If $S\cap i\mathbb{R}=\varnothing$ and $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R\cap\mathbb{C}_{-}}f(z)\,dz=0$, then $\int\limits_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\sum\limits_{s\in S\cap\mathbb{C}_{-}}\residue\limits_{z=s}f(z).$
> 3. If $S\cap i\mathbb{R}=\varnothing$ and $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R\cap\mathbb{C}_{+}}f(z)\,dz=0$, then $\int\limits_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}f(z)\,dz=-2\pi i\sum\limits_{s\in S\cap\mathbb{C}_{+}}\residue\limits_{z=s}f(z).$

(The first claim follows from the theorem immediately; the second is obtained by applying the theorem to the integral over $[-iR,iR]\cup(C_R\cap\mathbb{C}_{-})$ (and taking $R\to\infty$, of course); for the last one, we take $\mathbb{C}_{+}$ in place of $\mathbb{C}_{-}$, but get the opposite orientation of the contour, hence the change of sign.) The conditions above are usually checked using the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) or [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma). Another prerequisite we need is the [evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles) of residues at simple poles.

For example, the above is sufficient to prove $(1)$, understood as
$$\theta(u)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{e^{uz}\,dz}{z+\epsilon},$$
because if $u>0$ then the conditions in "2." are met, with
$$\residue_{z=-\epsilon}\frac{e^{uz}}{z+\epsilon}=\lim_{z\to-\epsilon}e^{uz}=e^{-u\epsilon}\underset{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}{\longrightarrow}1;$$
and if $u<0$ then the conditions in "3." are met (giving $0$); the case $u=0$ is solved by immediate evaluation, giving $\theta(0)=1/2$ with this definition.

Next, we follow the usual vector notation
\begin{align}
   a\pm b&:=\langle a_1\pm b_1,\ldots,a_n\pm b_n\rangle,
\\ \lambda a&:=\langle\lambda a_1,\ldots,\lambda a_n\rangle,
\\ ab&:=a_1 b_1+\ldots+a_n b_n
\end{align}
for $a=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $b=\langle b_1,\ldots,b_n\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. So, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n}e^{-au}\,du=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k},\qquad a\in \mathbb{C}_{+}^n.$$

---

Now let $n>1$ and consider slightly more general $$\color{blue}{Q(a,b)=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n}\min\{e^{-au},e^{-bu}\}\,du}$$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^n$ with $1,a_1/b_1,\ldots,a_n/b_n$ pairwise distinct. We get $(2)$ back with $$a=\langle\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\rangle,\qquad b=\langle 1,\ldots,1\rangle.$$

Let's go. Write $\min\{e^{-au},e^{-bu}\}=e^{-au}\theta\big((a-b)u\big)+e^{-bu}\theta\big((b-a)u\big)$, so that
\begin{align}
Q(a,b)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^n}(e^{-[a+z(b-a)]u}+e^{-[b+z(a-b)]u})\,du\,\frac{dz}{z+\epsilon}
\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\big(f(a,b,z)+f(b,a,z)\big)\,\frac{dz}{z+\epsilon},
\\f(a,b,z)&:=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(a_k+(b_k-a_k)z\big)^{-1}.
\end{align}
Under our assumptions, $f(a,b,z)$ has simple poles at $z=z_k:=\dfrac{a_k}{a_k-b_k}$ with
$$\residue_{z=z_k}\frac{f(a,b,z)}{z+\epsilon}=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z-z_k}{z+\epsilon}f(a,b,z)=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{a_k+(b_k-a_k)z}{(b_k-a_k)(z+\epsilon)}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_j+(b_j-a_j)z}\\=\frac{1}{(b_k-a_k)(z_k+\epsilon)}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{1}{a_j+(b_j-a_j)z_k}=-\frac{1}{a_k+(b_k-a_k)\epsilon}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{a_k-b_k}{a_k b_j-b_k a_j}.$$
Thus, applying the item "3." from the above, we get
$$Q(a,b)=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\a_k>b_k}}\frac{1}{a_k}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{a_k-b_k}{a_k b_j-b_k a_j}+\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant n\\b_k>a_k}}\frac{1}{b_k}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{b_k-a_k}{b_k a_j-a_k b_j},$$
or simply $\color{blue}{Q(a,b)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\max\{a_k,b_k\}}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{a_k-b_k}{a_k b_j-b_k a_j}}$. (We could also apply "2." instead, but then we would need to take care of the pole at $z=-\epsilon$. It leads to the RHS of the next equality.)

Finally, the analogue of your final equality (that you're asked to prove) is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{a_k-b_k}{a_k b_j-b_k a_j}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}.$$
This equality is proven using the item "1." from the above, applied to $\frac{f(a,b,z)}{z+\epsilon}$. It allows to write out alternative forms of $Q(a,b)$ (or, rather, to get back to the "blue" one above - perhaps it's the reason the final equality is given for).

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your answer! While working my way through your answers I stumbled across a question: As I mentioned I am very new to the Residuetheorem, so what do you mean in 5. when you say "closing with $C_R^+$? I know I need a closed curve for the theorem but I dont really see where $C_R^+$ is closed.

Comment: @TwoStones: After "4." we have $\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}$ which we interpret as $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int_{-iR}^{iR}$. This is where we add $C_R^{+}$ to the path of integration, making it closed. With $R\to\infty$, the integral over $C_R^{+}$ tends to $0$ (assuming $n>1$), and the whole integral becomes $-2\pi i$ times the sum of residues (at poles in the right halfplane). Cf. "1.".

Comment: I am very sorry, but I still have a little trouble understanding everything you wrote. How do you know how the residues look like? And can you maybe point out a little more what we can conclude in 7.?

Comment: Also when closing with $C_R^+$ there arent any poles in the domain or am I wrong here? The poles are at $z=-\epsilon$, $z= \frac{-a_j}{b_j - a_j}$ and $z=\frac{-b_j}{a_j -b_j}$ and those are all smaller than $0$ right?

Comment: That's OK, I'm just trying to put it short (having that much text already). I'll elaborate the evaluation of the residues a bit later. Regarding the poles: $-a_j/(b_j-a_j)>0$ when $a_j>b_j$. That's exactly why there are additional inequalities under $\sum$'s.

Comment: Ok, thank you .